# What are the advantages of the new line jungling? (i.e. Mundo, Maokai, Shyvana, Shen)

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been noticing a lot of play with Dr. Mundo ,Maokai, Shyvana, Shen. Not so much play from Warwick, Trundle and the likes. Why would you jungle or not jungle with any of these heroes?

Answer (score 2):

### How a jungler champion pick works?

- Clear his route fast (How long he takes in relation to the others)
- Gank Style. Synergy with your team composition.
- The need of the Blue. If your jungle don't need blue, your mid lane (or top) is more effective.

  1. As fast as you clear your jungle/shop. You can gank more efficiently, and with advantage of level (eg. You are 3 and the lane target is 2) and/or more gear (if you clear your route fast, shop and get back ready to gank without fall behind in level)
  2. Some champions have a better synergy with others. eg. Maokai works really nice with meele/short ranged types like Akali or Xin Zhao.
  3. Champions that don't need blue (energy based) and champions that can use blue, but don't need it to keep ganking, will give your mid lane or your top/bot lane a better sustainability and they can spam more skills. eg. Maokai, if you are not using his ult and has Phil.Stone, but Fiddle has more need of it.

---

**tl;dr;**

See how your team is, try fit the best jungler champion for them. When possible (draft) check how your opponent team is as well and try get the best counter for they jungler/laners.

Comment: IMO as long as you have solid gankability the clear speed isn't too important - Maok being a good example of that.

Comment: @user1090190 Maokai is one of the faster junglers at the moment. His snare and knock-back/slow and his sappling to last hit after the opponent flash, make his ganks very powerful. As fast as you do your jungle, as fast you're gonna gank

Comment: Comparing olaf/mundo/trundle to maok his clear speeds are relatively slow. And really, if you're doing a full clear on your jungle before ganking you're ganking way too late.

Answer (score 0):

The champions you mentioned have a pretty good clear time except for Shen. I've played as Dr. Mundo and I'm about 30 seconds above than the time it takes my Rammus to jungle. Mundo also has a pretty good ganking potential since if a cleaver lands you should land the rest. And you could also attack for red debuff. This also goes for Maokai. He has a decent clear time, but his ganks are amazing due to snare, slow and knockback. I would jungle as these since they are helpful late game, they initiate pretty well, they can save your team, and their ganks are pretty good. I cannot answer the rest as I do not play those champions.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with clear time mainly.

Take a jungler like Maokai. He has two abilities that have AOE effects (Three if you count his ultimate). Maokai performs well in a jungle with weaker creeps because he can clear it quickly.

Now take a jungler like Warwick. He has no AOE abilities, and thus must kill targets one at a time. This ends up becoming a disadvantage in the new jungle, because he cannot clear these weaker camps as quickly as champion with AOE.

With that said, you can see why certain champs are getting more play with the new jungle changes. It doesn't make them better or worse, it just means there are certain champs with a faster clear now.